# Jenkins fail with Fastlane

Tags: ios, jenkins, continuous-integration, fastlane

My job on a MacMini, using Jenkins, is failing. The job is consisted by a script that will execute some unit tests with Fastlane for iOS. The job executes correctly, but just after the build it logs the error:

```
FATAL: Remote call on SLAVE failed
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Classloading from system classloader disabled
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader$ClassLoaderProxy.fetch4(RemoteClassLoader.java:834)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader$ClassLoaderProxy.fetch3(RemoteClassLoader.java:867)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor72.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:896)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.CallableDecorator.call(CallableDecorator.java:19)
    at hudson.remoting.CallableDecoratorList$1.call(CallableDecoratorList.java:21)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at ......remote call to channel(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1554)
    at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:172)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:260)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.fetch3(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.findClass(RemoteClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:292)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixReflection.<clinit>(ProcessTree.java:699)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.kill(ProcessTree.java:647)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.killRecursively(ProcessTree.java:668)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.killRecursively(ProcessTree.java:667)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$Unix.killAll(ProcessTree.java:589)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$KillTask.call(Launcher.java:1091)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$KillTask.call(Launcher.java:1082)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:181)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:52)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused: java.lang.LinkageError
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixReflection.<clinit>(ProcessTree.java:710)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.kill(ProcessTree.java:647)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.killRecursively(ProcessTree.java:668)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.killRecursively(ProcessTree.java:667)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$Unix.killAll(ProcessTree.java:589)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$KillTask.call(Launcher.java:1091)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$KillTask.call(Launcher.java:1082)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:181)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:52)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
    at ......remote call to IOS-SLAVE(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1554)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:281)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:839)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Remote call on SLAVE failed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:847)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher.kill(Launcher.java:1079)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:502)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1737)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:419)
Finished: FAILURE
```

The current version of JDK I am running is 1.8.0_151 and Jenkins version is 2.73.

Comment: have you setup a master-slave jenkins? what is 'IOS-SLAVE'?

Answer (score 1):

try to update your jenkins to latest version and don't forget update his plugin too, then restart jenkins

Hope this helps,

Best regards